# Cold Start and First Price Auctions

Tags: logistic, decision-theory

I have the following contrived scenario... I've participated on various auction platforms where I bid on widgets. Assume that win/loss outcomes on individual platforms are well-separated such that for each platform `k` there exists a positive value `x_k` where `P(win|bid>x_k) = 1` and `P(win|bid<=x_k) = 0`. There is a new platform `k'` where I can bid on widgets. I want to determine `x_k` as quickly as possible.

I can overcome the cold start problem to finding `x_k'` by modeling a win probability curve `P(win|bid==x)` derived from my performance on the other platforms. Such a model would help determine where to make my first bid. Based on the win/loss outcome from that first bid, how should I bid in successive auctions on platform `k'`?

In a way, this feels like it becomes a binary search problem after the cold start but that becomes impractical when you consider that I would not want to overbid some value `z` such that `z >> x_k'`. Doing so would lead me to go broke in a real-world example. Is there a way to continue to use the win probability curve from the historical performance as a soft prior combined with the hyper-relevant early outcomes on this new platform to find `x_k'` in a way that is both "fast" and financially prudent?

Comment: This may be better suited for https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or maybe https://or.stackexchange.com/